# How to fix error : Call to a member function getPathName() on null in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload a video from my website and at the same time upload youtube.

This is code HTML

```html
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-simple">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <div class="lesson content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-header row">
                <div class="content-header-left col-md-6 col-xs-12 mb-1">
                    <h4 class="content-header-title"><a href="#"> Bài giảng </a></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-body">
                <div class="lesson-left col-md-8">
                    <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 m-0 box-shadow-1">
                        <textarea class="lesson-title" rows="1" placeholder="Thêm tiêu đề" name="title"></textarea>
                        <textarea class="lesson-content" rows="1" placeholder="Thêm nội dung" name="content"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="lesson-right col-md-4">
                    <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 box-shadow-1">
                        <h4 class="content-header-title">Video</h4>
                        <input type="file" name="video">
                    </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Below is function to upload video

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminBaseController;
    use Youtube;

    class LessonController extends AdminBaseController
    {
        function save(Request $request)
        {
            $video = Youtube::upload($request->file('video')->getPathName(), [
            'title'       => 'My Video',
            'description' => 'This video is uploaded through API.',
             'tags'        => ['api', 'youtube'],
            ]);

            return $video->getVideoId();
        }
    }
```

When i test, it appears an error:

> Call to a member function getPathName() on null

Comment: Can you post your full form from the view please? Are you maybe missing the `enctype` attribute on the form?

Comment: I already updated

Comment: `$request->file('video')` this returns null, that is why you cant call `getPathName()` function on null. please check whether your request hat video file or not. and you can solve solving this issue by checking a simple `if($request->file('video'))` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your form, you are missing the `enctype` which allows file uploads:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-simple" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And the **action** of course.

The problem is that your `$request->file('video')` in the controller is `null` hence the reason for the exception.

So it is better to always check if there is a file first, then proceed with the upload, add a guard for example like this:

```
if ( ! $request->hasFile('video') )
{
    return back()->withError('No file uploaded');
}
```

Or if `hasFile` for some reason always returns `false` just replace it with `$request->file('video')` which returns `null` if not video, so again the check will work.

Comment: yes, i missing enctype and $request->file('video') is null. I don't know whether my video is not allowed?

Comment: @TrucPham do you see the video now when you added the enctype ? You are still not reaching the YouTube code if it is null so what do you think is not allowed ? I don't understand.

Comment: I'm a newbie so there are a lot of things that I don't really understand. I do not know how to solve when $request->file('video) is null. Can you show me the details?

Comment: @TrucPham I already showed you above. Add the guard code the `if` statement as first few lines in your controller function. That will check if a file exists. If not it will redirect back with an error message that you can show in your view.